# python to "stream" dictionary processing

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, streaming

I have an algorithm in python that does an exhaustive search of possibilities given a set of inputs.

This is hooked up to a web application and can take up to 15 seconds to fully process.

So...yes I want to eventually improve on the algo and process quicker, but I'd also like to include a visualization that streams the possibilities python is working with until it arrives at a solution.

In my terminal, python generates the list of possibilities line by line until it finds a combo that satisfies the requirements

**How can I hook Python's terminal output up with my client-side framework**

Ideally it would simulate the terminal's output and the user can see evidence that the algo is running while they wait.

Would I convert the output to bytes, open a socket, and then stream the data within my application as I deserialize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using websockets.  Generally, you would have a separate socket server running, like [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/).  Both your web server and client-side javascript would connect to the socket server and communicate back and forth, or in your case, just continuously sending messages to the client.

Comment: Does it make a difference that I'm using Django on the backend? I see that there are libraries such as this https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio. is this the right tool for what I'm trying to accomplish or is there an easier one?

Comment: It doesn't matter what backend you're using.  You can use the `gevent-socketio` implementation, or just use the normal nodejs socket.io.  Either way it's generally running as a separate process/server.

Comment: if I used node.js socket.io (more familiar with that platform), I'd just implement something like this then? https://gist.github.com/mattgorecki/1375505. I have a node.js server that serves my client-side data so I might just use that one. Thanks for answering my follow up btw. if you don't answer I'll just go down the node path